# iOS autofocus while CIDetect facial detection

Tags: objective-c, face-detection

Currently I use CIDetect to detect face from a AVCaptureVideoDataOutput, I want to snap the picture when detected. However it seems CIDetect is very sensitive and the pictures I snapped are very blurry (ie. before iphone camera autofocus kicks in), is there a way to make CIDetect wait for autofocus before returning true?

Answer (score 0):

`CIDetector` tells you there are faces in the image. `AVCaptureDevice` has an observable property `adjustingFocus` you will need to check or observe in addition to the array of faces returned by `CIDetector`.